# Merge a php array and a php object

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I want to merge an `array` like first element to an `object` like second element.
Is it possible to merge a php object and a php array? If so, How do I merge these?

I have snipped via `print_r`

First Element (array)

```
Array
(
    [start_date] => 2014-12-28
)
```

Second Element (object)

```
Bannerlookup Object
(
    [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
    [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => First Banner
            [description] => My first banner description goes here
            [type] => 1
            [position] => 1
            [price] => 20
            [status] => 1
        )

    [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => 
    [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 1
    [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t
    [_errors:CModel:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [_validators:CModel:private] => 
    [_scenario:CModel:private] => update
    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert the object to array.

```
$new_array = json_decode(json_encode($your_object), true);
```

Now merge it with the existing array.

```
$merged_array = array_merge( $old_array, $new_array) ;
```

merging will cause the same `key` override by the second array. See [Array Merge Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Thanks buddy for quick reply.It really helped me. :) As YII's model object standard I have done like this               $obj_to_array=json_decode(json_encode($model->attributes), true);  This may help others.... :). And I am aware about key overriding while array merging. Cheers....

Answer (score 1):

wow you can do this with more readeblilty and much easier like

```
$combination = CMap::mergeArray($my_array, $my_model->attributes);
```

every model has a function `getAttributes()` which will give you an array of models attributes, and then you can use that, no `NEED` of **JSONENCODEDECODE**ing it :D

Comment: It sounds really interesting. I APPRECIATE this method for YII users. This is the one what I was searching for. I wasn't aware about CMap of YII. I will try this, When I need this again. Anyway thanks for your great answer... :)